# Python3: ResourceWarning Unclosed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, cloudflare

I have a Reddit Bot coded in Python where sometimes I get the following error:

> sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed ssl.SSLSocket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.113', 55513), raddr=('198.41.209.140', 443)>

`192.168.1.113` is my local IP and `198.41.209.140` is apparently CloudFlare's IP

I also sometimes get the following error which makes me think the problem is related to SSL?

> Error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:598)

How do I fix this issue?

Edit: How do I see what part of my code is causing this issue? I have an exception in my try/except to print all exceptions as:

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Login/API Error", e)
```

but all the errors i get do not have this which means it is not an exception?

Comment: The ResourceWarning says that the program exited without closing the socket.  An exception is one possible reason, as it may cause an explicit close.  A solution is to use a `with` statement and a context manager.

Comment: How would I narrow down the issue of where thin my code the problem lies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used sockets in my own code, so the following is based on my general Python knowledge.

The socket docs do not say that a `socket.socket` instance is a context manager, but the class has the requisite `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.  Both are standard, minimal, implementations.  It is possible you might want to subclass socket or SSLSocket to do something more in `__exit__`, such as printing your substitute for a traceback.  But to start, you need to see the full tracebacks.  Subclass `SSLSocket` inherits both methods.  Since an SSLSocket "wraps" a socket, there are apparently two objects to be concerned with.  So I would start with the following (untested, obviously) for the top level structure of your code:

```
<preliminary code>
with socket.socket(...) as sock  # or other socket-returning function
  <more preparation>
  with ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ...) as SSLsock # or the context function
    <use SSLsock to communicate>
```

The error message you got should have been prefixed with `SSLEOFError`.  Was it?  The doc says "A subclass of SSLError raised when the SSL connection has been terminated abruptly. Generally, you shouldn’t try to reuse the underlying transport when this error is encountered."  This is definitely an Exception.

```
>>> issubclass(ssl.SSLEOFError, Exception)
True
```

What might provoke Cloudfare into terminating the connection 'abruptly'?  A bug in its protocol handling; a bug in ssl.py?  Does your bot somehow violate Terms of Service?

If you can't get all answers you need here, I would try `python-list`, also accessible as newsgroup `gmane.comp.python.general` at `news.gmane.org`.  It has participants with network experience.